# probmem with comparing string c++

Tags: c++, string, compare

I just came from C to C++ and find difficulties with compare string method.
I have a simple task. I need to create a class of school Teachers, then make an object array, and after withdrow all Teachers, who's subject is similar to testSubject.

So here is my class

```
class Teacher 
{
private:

    string FamilyName;
    string Name;
    string Patronymic;
    string sex;
    int exp;
    std::string subject;
    string speciality;
    int age;


public:

    Teacher(); 
    int getExp();
    string getSubject();
    int getAge();
    void show();

};
```

And here is my func, that withdrow the list of Teachers, teaching the input subject

```
void ListTeacherSub (Teacher spis[], int n)
{
//List of teachers, who's subject is like testSubject
std::string testSubject;
cout<<"Enter test subject "; cin>>testSubject;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (spis[n].getSubject().compare(testSubject) == 0)
        spis[i].show();
}        
}
```

Here it is main() function

```
int main() 
{
Teacher *spis;
int n;
cout<<"Enter numbers of student "; cin>>n;
spis = new Teacher[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{    
 spis[i].show();
}

ListTeacherAge(spis, n);
ListTeacherEx(spis, n);
ListTeacherSub(spis, n);

 delete[] spis;
 return 0;
}
```

So, everything is working nice, but when program reaches ListTeacherSub(spis, n) it is stops working. I used to work with strcmp only, but it doesn't works with string, as I understood. 
So I decided to look for different realizations, and found that one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

How can i fix my problem?

Comment: "it stops working" -- what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if (spis[n].getSubject().compare(testSubject) == 0)
```

should be

```
if (spis[i].getSubject().compare(testSubject) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect (and causes undefined behaviour as it going beyond the end of the array):

```
if (spis[n].getSubject().compare(testSubject) == 0)
```

as it using `n` and not the loop counter `i`.

Other:

- always check the result of input operations to ensure variables have been correctly populated and subsequent code is not using uninitialised or stale values:

  ```
  if (std::cin >> n)
  {
      spis = new Teacher[n];
  }
  ```
- prefer to avoid explicit dynamic memory management. In this case [`std::vector<Teacher>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be suitable:

  ```
  if (std::cin >> n)
  {
      std::vector<Teacher> spis(n);
      for (Teacher& t) t.show();
  }
  ```

Pass `spis` by `const Teacher&` to functions to avoid copy (and the parameter `n` is now superfluous).

- `std::string` instances can be compared using [`==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).